# 2 set of Radio Button in form

Tags: html, radio-button, forms

in my form, two set of radio button is used for award and handicapped checking..
when am click on the radio button, it will checked and value will be entered into the database. this musc is ok. but the problem is that, in display form it does not showing the clicked one. All are in unchecked form.

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
      <td width="418" align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><?php echo "Handicap : $Handicap ---- Award : $Award <br>"; ?> Are you physically challenged?</td><td>Yes:<input type="radio" name="C135_Handicap" id="C135_Handicap_y" value="Y" <?php if(isset($Handicap)){$status=(htmlentities($Handicap, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')=='Y')?'checked':'unchecked';echo $status;}?>  />  
        No:
          <input type="radio" name="C135_Handicap" id="C135_Handicap_n" value="N"  <?php if(isset($Handicap)){$status=(htmlentities($Handicap, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')=='N')?'checked':'unchecked';echo $status;}?> /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"><p>Have you received any State/District level awards </p>
        <p>or Other Recognition:</p></td>
      <td width="393">Yes:<input type="radio" id="C135_Award_y" name="C135_Award" value="Y"  <?php if(isset($Award)){$status=(htmlentities($Award, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')=='Y')?'checked':'unchecked';echo $status;}?>/> 
        No:
        <input type="radio" name="C135_Award" id="C135_Award_n"  value="N" <?php if(isset($Award)) $status=(htmlentities($Award, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')=='N')?'checked':'unchecked';echo $status; ?> /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have two radios or two sets of radios? Are you saying when you run the program and click on the radio button it won't activate?

Comment: Could you post some code? Are you talking about a web form or the GUI of a desktop application? Having code, it would be a lot easier to see what your problem is.

Comment: You can edit your question, using the small link below of it. For pasting (HTML)-Code see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) on meta.

Comment: Can you show us how/where $Award and $Handicap are set? What is the action of the form?

Comment: have you tried any jquery? http://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/implementing-a-more-usable-and-attractive-radio-button-group-with-jquery-and-php/